# Cython installed but no cdefs in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cython

I just installed cython and I have a problem in Visual Studio 2017.

I wrote a simple program:

```
import cython

def SimpleProgram():

    cdef int i
```

The "import cython" shows cython in pink, which is the color in Visual Studio for modules that are in installed, so based on that the installation appears to be correct.

But the "cdef" in cdef int i, j does not show in blue (it's white), indicating that it does recognize cdef.

Is there some extra installation step I need for Visual Studio?  I didn't see anything about it in the installation instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for cython syntax in visual studio right now, but it can be added through an extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=guyskk.language-cython

As for why, apparently they are waiting for support to be added to [Magic Python](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython).

Other factors that might cause this in the future could include:

- if you didn't end your filename with the correct extension `.cy` or `.pyx` in windows

Comment: Thanks much, @iggy12345.  That extension is for Visual Studio Code -- do you know if they have one for Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: From what I can tell, you can install any extension from the visual studio marketplace into either visual code, or studio, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019#install-or-uninstall-visual-studio-extensions)